# Why do Quantum Annealer have (currently) a higher scaling potential?

Tags: d-wave, annealing

One may categorize quantum computers in two classes: Quantum Annealer and (universal) Gate Quantum Computers. There may be also other categories. IBM announced 127 Qubits for their next Gate Quantum Computer, while the Quantum Annealer implemented by D-Wave easily offer some 5000 Qubits. Quantum Annealer differ from Gate Quantum Computers but on the implementation level the systems are both based on superconducting elements. To some extend the Qubits may be similar but why is it so much easier to scale up Quantum Annealers compared to Gate Quantum Computers?

My understanding is that Quantum Annealer are not so much concerned about coherence and noise to some level is something useful for adiabatic computing. Also, the D-Wave Qubits are only connected to a maximum of six Qubits, while for Gate Quantum Computers you would like to connect as many Qubits as possible?

Comment: Saying that D-wave and other annealers have "qubits" is a bit disingenuous. They're not really qubits in the traditional sense, in that you can't control them using traditional gate operations.

Comment: Note that on IBM Q the connections among qubits are restricted. Have a look at any diagram of IBM processor.